# How do I position a passwordToggleDrawable in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, passwords, android-drawable

The following link shows the main problem ([Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhkqQ.jpg))
As you can see, there is overlap between the password visibility icon and the validation icon (when it dynamically appears). I want to know a simple way to position the icons so that they will work together, is that possible?

**The password toggle**

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutWifiPW"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutWifiSSID"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/passwordtoggle"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/md_blue_500">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="568dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"

            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SSID" />
```

**Validation methods**

```
private void validateWIFI(final Context context) {
        if (SSID.length() == 0 ) {
            dialogButtonTrueOrFalse(mDialog, false);
            SSID.setError(context.getString(R.string.error_ssid_empty));
        }else if (PWD.length() > 0 && PWD.length() < 8) {
            dialogButtonTrueOrFalse(mDialog, false);
            PWD.setError(context.getString(R.string.error_pwd_length));
        }else {
            dialogButtonTrueOrFalse(mDialog,true);
        }
    }
    public void dialogButtonTrueOrFalse(AlertDialog mDialog, Boolean button){
        if (button){
            mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setClickable(true);
            mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);
        }else if (!button){
            mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setClickable(false);
            mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for change drawable, create a selector like below

password_toggle_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_visible" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_password_hidden"/>
</selector>
```

then assign to TextInputLayout like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/PasswordLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    **app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_toggle_drawable"**
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.CommonTextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/PasswordEditText"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

for height, I used below code after inflating:

```
CheckableImageButton text_input_password_toggle = (CheckableImageButton) PasswordLayout().findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.text_input_password_toggle);
text_input_password_toggle.setMinimumHeight(0);
PasswordEditText().setMinHeight(0);
PasswordEditText().setMinimumHeight(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

i tink you setError to CommonTextInputEditText and its better that 
you setError TextInputLayout instead of your CommonTextInputEditText in your java codes

```
TextInputLayout  passwordInputLayout =findViewById(R.id.textInputLayoutWifiPW);
passwordInputLayout.setError("your textError");
```

you can use this [refrence](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/) to learn about in

also you can setErrorStyle to your edittext and add margin to it

```
yourEditText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<//todo...'>this is the error</font>"));
```